# Set a view's textbox (datetime field) to display readonly current datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a textbox on my view and I'm only looking it to display the current date and time(in readonly..how can this be done?

Currently I have this in the view:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Opened, new { @value = System.DateTime.Now, @readonly = "readonly" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Opened)
    </div>
```

..And this in the model:

```
    [Required]
    public DateTime Opened
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

How can this be implemented in MVC?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do that, but @Angel Manuel Garcia Car's suggest is what you should be doing logically.

Anyways, here is the code. As long as you are creating a textbox, you should be using `TextBoxFor`.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Opened, new { @value = DateTime.Now, @readonly="readonly" })
```

I don't see any point here.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you using a Label. I think it's unusual display dates and time at TextBoxes.

Regards.

Comment: Using `label` is not semantically correct as the <label> tag defines a label for an <input> element.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I don't suggest the HTML label, if not the ASP.NET label (<asp:Label>).